# Do all positive elements in a C* algebra commute?

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let there be A, B positive elements in some C* algebra.
Now there holds: $$ AB = (AB)^* = B^*A^* = BA $$ since the product of A and B again gives a positive element, correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not true that all positive elements of a $C^*$ algebra commute. The problem with your argument is that it is not true that the product of two positive elements in a $C^*$ algebra must be positive.

Comment: And indeed, hermitian elements $A$ and $B$ commute if and only if their product is hermitian.